# Can I remap key combos to key sequences in Linux/X?

Tags: xkb

Using something like `xkbmap`, is there any way to translate a single complicated "key event" such as `Ctrl-Super-F` or some Korean unicode char to a sequence of simpler events, say `C-x C-x C-a`, so that a simple tty terminal could interpret them?

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to cheat terminal emacs into behaving like GUI emacs :P

Comment: I'm guessing the answer the answer is "no" since you'd need cooperation from the program you're relaying the key events to (since they need a chance to register each event in the sequence). But writing a VTE just for this purpose sounds like a fun project :P

Answer (score 0):

`xdotool` can do exactly this! Cool!